# Does predict.H2OModel() from h2o package in R give OOB predictions for h2o.randomForest() models?

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I can't tell from documentation whether or not the `predict.H2OModel()` function from the `h2o` package in R gives OOB predictions for random forest models built using `h2o.randomForest()`.

In fact, in the 3-4 examples I've tried, it seems the results of `predict.H2OModel()` are closer to the non-OOB predictions from `predict.randomForest()` from the `randomForest` package than the OOB ones.

Does anyone know if they are OOB predictions?  If not, do you know how to get OOB predictions for `h2o.randomForest()` models?

Example:

```
set.seed(123)
library(randomForest)
library(h2o)

data(mtcars)
d = mtcars[,c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp', 'hp', 'wt' )]

## define some common settings for both random forests
n.trees=1000
mtry = 3  
min.node = 3

## prep for h2o.randomForest
h2o.init()  
d.h2o= as.h2o(d) 
x.names = colnames(d)[2:5] ## predictors

## fit both models
set.seed(123); 
rf  =     randomForest(mpg ~ .,                      data = d    ,  ntree=n.trees,   mtry = mtry, nodesize=min.node)
h2o = h2o.randomForest(y='mpg', x=x.names, training_frame = d.h2o, ntrees=n.trees, mtries = mtry, min_rows=min.node)

## Correct way and incorrect way of getting OOB predictions for a randomForest model. Not sure about h2o model. 
d$rf.oob.pred =           predict(rf)                  ## Gives OOB predictions
d$rf.pred     =           predict(rf , newdata=d    )  ## Doesn't give OOB predictions.
d$h2o.pred    = as.vector(predict(h2o, newdata=d.h2o)) ## Not sure if this is OOB or not.  

## d$h2o.pred seems more similar to d$rf.pred than d$rf.oob.pred, 
## suggesting that predict.H2OModel() might not give OOB predictions.
mean((d$rf.pred     - d$h2o.pred)^2)
mean((d$rf.oob.pred - d$h2o.pred)^2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2O's [h2o.predict()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/predict.H2OModel.html) does not provide predictions for the OOB data. You have to specify what dataset you want to predict with the `newdata =` parameter. So when you have `newdata=d.h2o` then you are getting the predictions for the `d.h2o` dataframe you've specified.

Currently there is no method to get the prediction for the oob data. However, there is a [jira ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5797) to specify whether you would like oob metrics (note this ticket also links to another ticket which helps clarify how training metrics are currently being reported for Random Forest).